# Passing by reference to signal handler

Tags: c++, gtk, pass-by-reference, gtk3, gtkmm

Compile with `g++ main.cc -Wall $(pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs)`

What it currently does:

> Displays a window with a simple `SpinButton`

What I want to do:

> Pass in a reference of `spinbutton` to the signal handler `on_spinbutton_change` so that I can `getAdjustment` and set the formatting (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9998968))

Question:

> How do I pass in a reference of `spinbutton` and optionally additional data (like a simple integer)?

main.cc (compiles fine, does not pass reference):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <gtkmm/spinbutton.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>

class HelloWorld : public Gtk::Window {
public:
    HelloWorld();
    virtual ~HelloWorld();

protected:
    static gboolean on_spinbutton_change();
    Gtk::SpinButton spinbutton;
};

HelloWorld::HelloWorld() {
    spinbutton.signal_output().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(&HelloWorld::on_spinbutton_change));
    add(spinbutton);
    spinbutton.show();
}

HelloWorld::~HelloWorld() {}

gboolean HelloWorld::on_spinbutton_change() {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");
    HelloWorld helloworld;
    return app->run(helloworld);
}
```

main.cc (does not compile, attempt to pass reference):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <gtkmm/spinbutton.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>

class HelloWorld : public Gtk::Window {
public:
    HelloWorld();
    virtual ~HelloWorld();

protected:
    static gboolean on_spinbutton_change(Gtk::SpinButton *spin);
    Gtk::SpinButton spinbutton;
};

HelloWorld::HelloWorld() {
    spinbutton.signal_output().connect(sigc::bind<Gtk::SpinButton*>(sigc::ptr_fun(&HelloWorld::on_spinbutton_change), spinbutton));
    add(spinbutton);
    spinbutton.show();
}

HelloWorld::~HelloWorld() {}

gboolean HelloWorld::on_spinbutton_change(Gtk::SpinButton *spin) {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");
    HelloWorld helloworld;
    return app->run(helloworld);
}
```

Comment: For this specific issue, sigc++ provides `sigc::ref()`. Please, try this: `spinbutton.signal_output().connect(sigc::bind<Gtk::SpinButton*>(sigc::ptr_fun(&HelloWorld::on_spinbutton_change), sigc::ref(spinbutton)));`. Without `sigc::ref()`, you either get an (uninteded) copy of `spinbutton` or it does not compile (when Gtk::SpinButton's copy constructor is deleted). (It's a while ago that I switched to Qt and I used gtkmm 2.4 before but I believe this shouldn't have changed.)

Comment: Using your suggested change, I get `error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(sigc::pointer_functor1<Gtk::SpinButton*, int>, sigc::reference_wrapper<Gtk::SpinButton>)’`.

Comment: However, changing line 12 to `static gboolean on_spinbutton_change(const Gtk::SpinButton &spin);`, line 17 to `spinbutton.signal_output().connect(sigc::bind(sigc::ptr_fun(&HelloWorld::on_spinbutton_change), sigc::ref(spinbutton)));` and line 24 to `gboolean HelloWorld::on_spinbutton_change(const Gtk::SpinButton &spin) {`, I am able to compile and run without errors. This is apparently because without `const`, the copy constructor is called. With this, I am still not able to set the `SpinButton`'s  value (because of `const`).

Comment: Any ideas on how to remove the `const` qualifier and still be able to run?

Comment: In your second sample code, the signature of callback is `static gboolean on_spinbutton_change(Gtk::SpinButton *spin);` i.e. the argument to be bound is a pointer. Binding a reference (or instance) should fail - type mismatch. In this case, you have to bind the address of `spinbutton`: `spinbutton.signal_output().connect(sigc::bind<Gtk::SpinButton*>(sigc::ptr_fun(&HelloWorld::on_spinbutton_change), &spinbutton));`. To make the previous binding with `sigc::ref()` working, the signature of callback has to be changed: `static gboolean on_spinbutton_change(Gtk::SpinButton &spin);`.

Comment: Please note, that unary `&` in _an expression_ is the address operator (inherited from C) but `&` in _a declaration_ is the _reference modifier_ (in C++ only). Same character, different meaning. (Confusing?) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit that I switched from gtkmm to Qt some years ago. Out of curiosity, I installed gtkmm 3 in my [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.org) (I'm on Windows 10) to prepare a sample (and find out how rusty I've become concerning gtkmm).

Considering the attempts of OP, I used multiple different signatures which can be used to achieve the same result.

1. `static gboolean Window::on_spinbtn_output_p(Gtk::SpinButton *pGtkSpinBtn);`
   the corresponding `connect()`:

   ```
   _gtkSpinBtn1.signal_output().connect(
     sigc::bind(
       sigc::ptr_fun(&Window::on_spinbtn_output_p),
       &_gtkSpinBtn1));
   ```
2. `static gboolean Window::on_spinbtn_output_r(Gtk::SpinButton &gtkSpinBtn);`
   the corresponding `connect()`:

   ```
   _gtkSpinBtn2.signal_output().connect(
     sigc::bind(
       sigc::ptr_fun(&Window::on_spinbtn_output_r),
       sigc::ref(_gtkSpinBtn2)));
   ```
3. `gboolean Window::on_spinbtn3_output()` (non-static)
   the corresponding `connect()`:

   ```
   _gtkSpinBtn3.signal_output().connect(
     sigc::mem_fun(this, &Window::on_spinbtn3_output));
   ```

The complete sample `testGtkSpinBtnSig.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <gtkmm/box.h>
#include <gtkmm/spinbutton.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>

class Window: public Gtk::Window {

  private:
    Gtk::VBox _gtkVBox;
    Gtk::SpinButton _gtkSpinBtn1;
    Gtk::SpinButton _gtkSpinBtn2;
    Gtk::SpinButton _gtkSpinBtn3;

  public:
    Window();
    virtual ~Window() = default;
    Window(const Window&) = delete;
    Window& operator=(const Window&) = delete;

  protected:
    static gboolean on_spinbtn_output_p(Gtk::SpinButton *pGtkSpinBtn);
    static gboolean on_spinbtn_output_r(Gtk::SpinButton &gtkSpinBtn);
    gboolean on_spinbtn3_output();
};

Window::Window(): Gtk::Window()
{
  _gtkSpinBtn1.set_range(0.0, 10.0); _gtkSpinBtn1.set_value(1.0);
  _gtkVBox.pack_start(_gtkSpinBtn1);
  _gtkSpinBtn2.set_range(0.0, 10.0); _gtkSpinBtn2.set_value(2.0);
  _gtkVBox.pack_start(_gtkSpinBtn2);
  _gtkSpinBtn3.set_range(0.0, 10.0); _gtkSpinBtn3.set_value(3.0);
  _gtkVBox.pack_start(_gtkSpinBtn3);
  add(_gtkVBox);
  _gtkVBox.show_all();
  // install signal handlers
  _gtkSpinBtn1.signal_output().connect(
    sigc::bind(
      sigc::ptr_fun(&Window::on_spinbtn_output_p),
      &_gtkSpinBtn1));
  _gtkSpinBtn2.signal_output().connect(
    sigc::bind(
      sigc::ptr_fun(&Window::on_spinbtn_output_r),
      sigc::ref(_gtkSpinBtn2)));
  _gtkSpinBtn3.signal_output().connect(
    sigc::mem_fun(this, &Window::on_spinbtn3_output));
}

gboolean Window::on_spinbtn_output_p(Gtk::SpinButton *pGtkSpinBtn)
{
  std::cout << "Window::on_spinbtn_output_p(): pGtkSpinBtn->get_value(): "
    << pGtkSpinBtn->get_value() << '\n';
  return true;
}

gboolean Window::on_spinbtn_output_r(Gtk::SpinButton &gtkSpinBtn)
{
  std::cout << "Window::on_spinbtn_output_r(): gtkSpinBtn.get_value(): "
    << gtkSpinBtn.get_value() << '\n';
  return true;
}

gboolean Window::on_spinbtn3_output()
{
  std::cout << "Window::on_spinbtn_output(): _gtkSpinBtn3.get_value(): "
    << _gtkSpinBtn3.get_value() << '\n';
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "Test SpinButton Signals");
  Window gtkWin;
  return app->run(gtkWin);
}
```

Compiled and tested:

```
$ g++ testGtkSpinBtnSig.cc -Wall $(pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs) -o testGtkSpinBtnSig

$ ./testGtkSpinBtnSig
Window::on_spinbtn_output_p(): pGtkSpinBtn->get_value(): 1
Window::on_spinbtn_output_r(): gtkSpinBtn.get_value(): 2
Window::on_spinbtn_output(): _gtkSpinBtn3.get_value(): 3
```

[image: Snapshot of testGtkSpinBtnSig]

---

Remembering, that OP actually wants to modify the formatting of the `GtkSpinButton` text another idea came into mind.

A notable extension of the gtkmm binding (in comparison to GTK+) is the fact that all the GTK+ widget class signals are provided as virtual methods. (I miss this feature very much in Qt where you have *either* virtual methods *or* signals but (IMHO) never both of them.) Practically, this means, in gtkmm you always have the option

- to make a derived widget class with enhanced capabilities (overloading the virtual methods for certain signals) or
- to modify the behavior of an individual instance (by connecting signal handlers).

Beside of this, it is, of course, also possible to derive a widget class which connects a method of its own to a signal inherited from the base class. (In gtkmm 2.4, I had to do this in the rare cases where the virtual methods were missing for GTK+ signals.)

So, I modified the above sample adding a derived `SpinButton` and changing the signal callbacks to format the spin button text.

`testGtkSpinBtnSig.cc`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <gtkmm/box.h>
#include <gtkmm/spinbutton.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>

std::string format(double value)
{
  std::ostringstream out;
  out << std::fixed << std::setw(4) << std::setprecision(1) << std::setfill('0')
    << value;
  return out.str();
}

class SpinButton: public Gtk::SpinButton {
  public:
    SpinButton (double climb_rate = 0.0, guint digits = 0):
      Gtk::SpinButton(climb_rate, digits)
    { }
    virtual ~SpinButton() = default;
    SpinButton(const SpinButton&) = delete;
    SpinButton& operator=(const SpinButton&) = delete;

  protected:
    virtual bool on_output() override;
};

bool SpinButton::on_output()
{
  const double value = get_value();
  set_text(format(value));
  return true;
}

class Window: public Gtk::Window {

  private:
    Gtk::VBox _gtkVBox;
    Gtk::SpinButton _gtkSpinBtn1;
    Gtk::SpinButton _gtkSpinBtn2;
    Gtk::SpinButton _gtkSpinBtn3;
    SpinButton _gtkSpinBtn4; // derived SpinButton

  public:
    Window();
    virtual ~Window() = default;
    Window(const Window&) = delete;
    Window& operator=(const Window&) = delete;

  protected:
    static gboolean on_spinbtn_output_p(Gtk::SpinButton *pGtkSpinBtn);
    static gboolean on_spinbtn_output_r(Gtk::SpinButton &gtkSpinBtn);
    gboolean on_spinbtn3_output();
};

Window::Window(): Gtk::Window()
{
  _gtkSpinBtn1.set_range(0.0, 10.0); _gtkSpinBtn1.set_value(1.0);
  _gtkVBox.pack_start(_gtkSpinBtn1);
  _gtkSpinBtn2.set_range(0.0, 10.0); _gtkSpinBtn2.set_value(2.0);
  _gtkVBox.pack_start(_gtkSpinBtn2);
  _gtkSpinBtn3.set_range(0.0, 10.0); _gtkSpinBtn3.set_value(3.0);
  _gtkVBox.pack_start(_gtkSpinBtn3);
  _gtkSpinBtn4.set_range(0.0, 10.0); _gtkSpinBtn4.set_value(4.0);
  _gtkVBox.pack_start(_gtkSpinBtn4);
  add(_gtkVBox);
  _gtkVBox.show_all();
  // install signal handlers
  _gtkSpinBtn1.signal_output().connect(
    sigc::bind(
      sigc::ptr_fun(&Window::on_spinbtn_output_p),
      &_gtkSpinBtn1));
  _gtkSpinBtn2.signal_output().connect(
    sigc::bind(
      sigc::ptr_fun(&Window::on_spinbtn_output_r),
      sigc::ref(_gtkSpinBtn2)));
  _gtkSpinBtn3.signal_output().connect(
    sigc::mem_fun(this, &Window::on_spinbtn3_output));
}

gboolean Window::on_spinbtn_output_p(Gtk::SpinButton *pGtkSpinBtn)
{
  pGtkSpinBtn->set_text(format(pGtkSpinBtn->get_value()));
  return true;
}

gboolean Window::on_spinbtn_output_r(Gtk::SpinButton &gtkSpinBtn)
{
  gtkSpinBtn.set_text(format(gtkSpinBtn.get_value()));
  return true;
}

gboolean Window::on_spinbtn3_output()
{
  _gtkSpinBtn3.set_text(format(_gtkSpinBtn3.get_value()));
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "Test SpinButton Signals");
  Window gtkWin;
  return app->run(gtkWin);
}
```

Compiled and tested:

```
$ g++ testGtkSpinBtnSig.cc -Wall $(pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs) -o testGtkSpinBtnSig
```

[image: Snapshot of testGtkSpinBtnSig (2nd version)]

Comment: You're the *Scheff*, Scheff. Excellent detail with working examples. With the examples, the plus/minus buttons did not work for me (in disabled state). I got around this by using `setting(Gtk::Adjustment::create(50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))` along with `spinbutton(setting)`.

Comment: @jmpsabisb Good point. I assume the [+], [-] didn't work as I left the constructor's `climb_rate` argument out - default is `0.0`. I forgot to mention that the `Gtk::SpinButton` provides some "formatting" methods on its own. So, may be, a proper configuration is even sufficient without signal handling/overloading. However, I feel you're "on track". ;-)